# SpringMVCの@CookieValueアノテーションについて

Tags: spring, cookie

コントローラーで、@CookieValue("SESSIONID")アノテーションを使用することで、
HttpServletRequestからキーが"SESSIONID"のCookieの値を取得できるとありましたが、
うまく動作しませんでした。

localhostでの動作で、実際クライアントには何一つcookieが入っていない状態ですが、
その状態ではエラーが発生するということは、Spring側で、TOPページにアクセスされた際のクッキー取得には使わないという想定で実装されているということなのでしょうか？

発生したエラーは下記です。
このときCookieは何ももっていませんでした。

```
org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException: Missing cookie 'SESSIONID' for method parameter of type String
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(AbstractCookieValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:66) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:96) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CookieValue.html
にあるように、デフォルトではrequiredがtrueになっています。

```
@CookieValue(value="SESSIONID", required=false)
```

のようにすべきと思います。

あるいは、
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281821/spring-mvc-when-to-use-cookievalue
にある様に、

```
@CookieValue(value="SESSIONID", defaultValue="xxxxx")
```

でしょうか。これはどう使いたいかによりますね。